YDB Nodejs SDK: How to get the string representation of a type?
Does anyone know how to get the string representation of a type IType in ydb-nodejs-sdk? Maybe there is some enum or method, but I don't find anything. Here's a simple example to show what I mean.
import { Session, TypedData, Types, Ydb, declareType, snakeToCamelCaseConversion, withTypeOptions } from "ydb-sdk";

export type TestModelType = {
  id: string;
  value: string;
};

@withTypeOptions({namesConversion: snakeToCamelCaseConversion})
export class TestModel extends TypedData implements TestModelType {
  @declareType(Types.UTF8)
  id: TestModelType['id']

  @declareType(Types.UTF8)
  value: TestModelType['value']

  constructor(fields: TestModelType) {
    super(fields);
    this.id = fields.id;
    this.value = fields.value;
  }
}

export async function insertTest(session: Session, model: TestModel) {
  const query = `
    DECLARE $id AS ${doSomethingToGetFieldType(model.getType('id'))};
    DECLARE $value AS ${doSomethingToGetFieldType(model.getType('value'))};

    INSERT INTO \`tests\` (\`id\`, \`value\`)
    VALUES ($id, $value);
  `;

  const preparedQuery = await session.prepareQuery(query);
  await session.executeQuery(preparedQuery, {
    '$id': model.getTypedValue('id'),
    '$value': model.getTypedValue('value')
  });
}

function doSomethingToGetFieldType(field: Ydb.IType): string {
  // How to get the string representation of a type?
  // ...

  return '';
}


There isn't a built-in way to get the string representation directly from the Ydb.IType interface. But, you can create a mapping of Ydb.IType to their string representations.
YDB Node.js SDK comes with the Type class, which contains various static properties representing different types of YDB. Each of these property is an instance of a particular class or subclass of Type. You can create a map where keys are the class names of these types and the values are their string representation:
const Types = Ydb.Types;

function getYDBType(type: Ydb.IType): string {
  if (type === Types.Bool) {
    return 'Bool';
  }
  if (type === Types.Uint8) {
    return 'Uint8';
  }
  if (type === Types.Uint32) {
    return 'Uint32';
  }
  if (type === Types.Uint64) {
    return 'Uint64';
  }
  if (type === Types.Int8) {
    return 'Int8';
  }
  if (type === Types.Int32) {
    return 'Int32';
  }
  if (type === Types.Int64) {
    return 'Int64';
  }
  if (type === Types.Float) {
    return 'Float';
  }
  if (type === Types.Double) {
    return 'Double';
  }
  if (type === Types.UTF8) {
    return 'Utf8';
  }
  if (type === Types.JSON) {
    return 'Json';
  }
  if (type === Types.UUID) {
    return 'Uuid';
  }
  //... add other types as per requirements

  throw new Error('Unsupported YDB type ' + type);
}


function doSomethingToGetFieldType(field: Ydb.IType): string {
  return getYDBType(field);
}  

It's kinda manual to do this, but if you don't have so many types and don't want to check it all the time it shouldn't be a problem

.constructor.name of all types is 'Object'

you're right, I did this once and got confused about it, sorry. I've edited to the right way now
